# Unable to create AZURE CLASSIC storage account in west central us

Tags: powershell, azure, storage, azure-storage

I am trying to create Azure Classic Storage account using below commands in `West Central US` but it is throwing up error

> "Unable to create storage account 'xxxx': 'The location constraint is
>   not valid'.

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName "xxxxx" -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts" -Location "West Central US"  -Properties @{ AccountType = "Standard_LRS" }

New-AzureStorageAccount –StorageAccountName "xxx" -Location "West Central US" -Type Standard_LRS
```

But am able to create classic storage account in other locations.

Comment: try `westcentralus`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your subscription does not support classic storage accounts in “West Central US”, please try to manually create the classic storage account in this location in Azure portal and check whether you will see this warning.

[image]